# Write a predicate sqrt_list(NumberList, ResultList) to the list of pairs consisting of a number and its square root

Tags: list, prolog

Write a predicate `sqrt_list(NumberList, ResultList)` that binds `ResultList` to the list of pairs consisting of a number and its square root, for each number in `NumberList`.

For example:

```
?- sqrt_list([1,4,9], Result).
Result = [[1,1.0], [4,2.0], [9,3.0]].  % expected
```

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question, but do not reuse an existing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the meta-predicate `maplist/3` in combination with [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl):

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

list_withsqrts(Es, Xss) :-
   maplist(\E^[E,S]^(S is sqrt(E)), Es, Xss).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_withsqrts([1,4,9], Xss).
Xss = [[1,1.0], [4,2.0], [9,3.0]].
```

---

A few notes:

1. Using fixed-length lists instead of compound terms of the same arity is generally regarded as bad coding style.
2. Finding good relation names is an important Prolog programming skill. In above code I used `list_withsqrts` instead of `sqrt_list`. Not famous, but arguably somewhat better...

Answer (score 0):

keep dividing the original list into sublist, taking one number as head and rest as a tail. repeat the same and Note that the Prolog built-in function sqrt computes the square root and that it needs to be evaluated using is to actually do the computation:
example:

```
?- X is sqrt(5).
X = 2.23606797749979.
```

then add each result to the resultList head with numberList. as,

```
 ResultHead=[Head|[SquareRoot]]
```